# How to use regex over zgrep?

Tags: linux, unix, find, archive

I need to find some values inside a zipped file such as `.tar` or `.zip`.
I found that this command was useful to bring me what I need:

```
find . | xargs zgrep --color=always "blabla"
```

Except the "blabla" I also need to find some other string which is after or before it.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

I added some arguments to find so you will only grep in these files.

```
find . -name "*.gz" -type f | xargs zgrep -B1 -A1 --color=always "blabla"
```

Answer (score 0):

`zgrep` is using grep so, you can use the `-a` option from `grep`:

From the `man` page:

> -a, --text
>
> Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.

If you want to find something on the same 'line', use a wildcard like this:

`find . | xargs zgrep -a --color=always "before_bla.*blabla.*after_bla"`

To directly answer your question `man grep`.

Be careful grepping in a zip file though.

Comment: Well your suggestion doesn't work. What did you mean about `man grep` ?

Comment: reading the grep manual page
also available [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)